# How to get a list of uncommited files on svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, report

We are currently editing code under svn directly on a shared folder (our test server).
As we can push files directly from test to prod, it is quite easy to 'forget' to commit files under SVN...

In order to avoid bad surprises and having svn completely out of sync, I'd like to generate a report of uncommited files (with the name of the person who changed it last) so I can send a weekly reminder about commiting changes.

I have found a couple of tools like statsvn in order to generate reports, but it only provides very technical details (number of lines added...).

Does anyone here have ever done that? How would you approach it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean, uncommitted files in a local working copy?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but 'svn status' gives you the list of modified files. ( see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html ). It's quite hard to give you a way to list the last person who changed the files without more information about your setup (filesystem, os, etc).

However, I doubt the workflow you're using is really secure. Why don't all the developers have their own checkout of the SVN repository ? It seems to me that using a shared folder is really a bad idea and can lead to many problems.

Comment: Our setup is the following: IIS6 - Windows 2003 - ColdFusion Application Server - Commonspot CMS. 

We know that the way it is done is not optimal. The main reason for that is that we not have dev versions of the CMS (which require an Oracle database). Therefore, files have to be run from the server itself. 

The problems you are mentioning are exactly what we are currently facing.

I'll check the link you sent ASAP. I also believe that unadded files can be tracked down by looking at the ownership of the file at NTFS level.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really answer your precise question, but continuous integration (checking that the project builds and run tests at each commit) will help you, as automatic checks at each commit will fail if a file was not committed

Comment: Unfortunately, the projects were not built with testing in mind. We are running ColdFusion. Therefore, no compilation is required and Unit Testing is close to non-existent. :-(
Here, I'm trying to maintain legacy code and trying to improve process. If you have any tool to recommend for continuous integration, I'll be happy to hear about them.

Comment: @Japetto googling "cold fusion continuous integration" showed some results (cannot judge if they can be used in your situation as I'm ignorant in ColdFusion), maybe you can dig this way. See for example this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326154/using-maven-for-coldfusion-project

Comment: Thanks @CharlesB, it does definitely help! :-)

Comment: Cool, of course upvoting an answer you like is considered as good practice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just grep the output of svn stat, for example:

```
$ svn stat|grep "^\?"
?       doc
?       gcc/firmware.bin
?       gcc/mc.bin
?       gcc/mc.elf
?       gcc/platform.c
```